# Cannot install Ruby 1.9.2 using rvm on MAC osx

Tags: ruby, learn-ruby-the-hard-way

I am trying to learn some ruby using the book Learn Ruby the Hard Way. The book asssumes you use ruby version 1.9.2 . It also recommends using rvm to install this version of ruby. I am trying to on Mac OS. I have 2 macs and have tried installing this version on both multiple times. Both of them have the same error in both scenarios. I have successfully installed other versions of ruby on these machines using rvm.

Here is the error in question for each mac

```
RVM does not know how to build working ruby-1.9.2-p330 on OSX 13.2,
if you know please let us know by opening a ticket with instructions here:
```

The same error occurs on my other mac but for a different OSX version. Is this just something that I will not be able to do? I don't mind using another version of Ruby as long as it doesn't mess with my practice using this book. Any insight or solution would be most welcome! Thanks!

I have tried installing using

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

I have also used different machines to try and install

Comment: Maybe try 1.9.3 or use a newer addition of the book? https://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex0.html

Comment: For learning Ruby, try using version 3.0 and newer.
Most tutorials will work with that version, and you get some goodies that are not mentioned in old tutorials.

The 1.9 version is archaic in Ruby World.

Check the `eol` (end of life) versions here -> https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/branches/

The lowest version you should start with should be the 2.7 (as it is the latest eol version).

Comment: You have one more option with RVM, list the known Rubies with `rvm list known`. Then you can select the one that is closest to your version. But I strongly suggest version 3.0 as mentioned in the previous comment.